# What is the role of executor function in Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback, es6-promise

When we write the below code

```
let promy = new Promise(executor(resolve,reject){
     if(1 === 2)
     resolve(1);
     else
     reject("No One");
});

promy.
then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(string){
   console.log(string);
});
```

In the above code I understand that

1. Promise is initially in pending state when resolve or reject gets invoked it's state changes to fulfilled or reject
2. when resolve is invoked inside executor the function inside then is triggered and whatever value is passed by resolve that value is captured inside this function. similar things happens with reject

What I am not getting is when we write that executor function inside Promise (..) that means the Promise Constructor will be called and we will pass this entire executor function to this constructor right. So then

1. what that constructor will do with this executor function?
2. How it will process this executor and what that constructor will return here? what will be that value.
3. How we will use that return value

Actually I see there are many things happening all at once like executor function is sent to the Constructor and the resolve or reject function are also getting called within the executor function at same time. This confuses me a lot with so many things happening.

The sequence of events are looking haphazard to me so not able to trace it. With this feeling even if I understand how to write promise syntax not getting satisfied that I fully understood it.

As I am new to JavaScript if somebody explains this in simple terms that will be highly appreciable.I have read many answers for this but sometimes I get bogged down by the complexity of answers as the way they are explained or sometimes the above queries are not explained at all

Comment: the role is to resolve or reject the promise

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise Its just a callback function that gets a `resolve` and `reject` function passed as arguments

Comment: But what does the constructor do with that function how it handles